# Background-size: cover versus background-size: contain

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

This is what I need to achieve with my HTML/CSS, the text should always be inside the green container, no matter what the screen size is.

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<section id="aboutprocess">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <p class="text-center">Our agile team continuously delivers working software and empowers your organization to embrace changing requirements.
                    </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block white" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">about our process</button>
                </div>
                <!--end col-md-8 col-md-offset-2-->
            </div>
            <!--end row -->
        </div>
        <!--end container-->
    </section>
    <!--end aboutprocess-->
```

In order to achieve this view, I've used `background-size: contain` + `flexbox`:

```
#aboutprocess {
        background: url("../img/tech_bg.png") no-repeat left top;
        width: 100%;
        height: 588px;
        background-size: contain;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #aboutprocess p {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

When I resize the window, the text falls outside:

[image]

When I use `background-size cover`, the green background image doesn't show the original shape any more:

[image]

How could I make it work that this green background remains its shape and text stays on this background aligned both vertically and horizontally.

Here is the link [to the demo page](http://dolm.ragne.me/).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using contain remove the fixed height and use % instead to keep the proportion ... but anyway at some point the img could be too small to keep the layout you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused as you have a fixed height for your container - it needs to keep the aspect ratio of the background image to work properly

Using the [padding css ratio hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/), you can get the container to keep the aspect ratio and then position the row accordingly:

```css
#aboutprocess {
  background: url("http://dolm.ragne.me/img/tech_bg.png") no-repeat left top;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
#aboutprocess .container {
  padding-top:  32.6316%;
  position:relative;
}
#aboutprocess .row {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0; 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
#aboutprocess .col-md-8 {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutprocess">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <p class="text-center">Our agile team continuously delivers working software and empowers your organization to embrace changing requirements.
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block white" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">about our process</button>
      </div>
      <!--end col-md-8 col-md-offset-2-->
    </div>
    <!--end row -->
  </div>
  <!--end container-->
</section>
```